# what is wrong with this java regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
final static private Pattern includePattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s+([^\\s]*)");

...

Matcher mtest = includePattern.matcher("   this.txt");
String ftest = mtest.group(1);
```

I get an exception `No match found at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)`

I'm looking for at least 1 space character followed by a captured group of nonspace characters. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll first need to call `.find()` before you can use `group(...)`.

Note that `find()` returns a `boolean`, so it's safe(r) to do something like this:

```
final static private Pattern includePattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s+([^\\s]*)");
Matcher mtest = includePattern.matcher("   this.txt");
String ftest = m.find() ? mtest.group(1) : null;
```

And `[^\\s]` could be rewritten as `\\S` (capital `s`).

You might have simplified your example a bit in your question, but I assume you're aware of the fact that `String.trim()` takes care of any leading and trailing white space characters.

Comment: I can't for another 10 minutes.